# Checking condition while GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, case, conditional-statements

How can I efficiently check if at least one record exists in group. In case two condition are met then I would like to have it in results.

I do it now by in the first step

```
select 
worker,
,help_column_A=sum(case when condition='A' then 1 else 0 end)
,help_column_B=sum(case when condition='B' then 1 else 0 end)
from table
group by
worker
```

then in second step I do:

```
select 
case when help_column_A>0 and when help_column_B>0 then 'A and B'
case when help_column_A>0 then 'A'
case when help_column_B>0 then 'B'
end
```

The data is a large set and definitely I do not need to count the A or B to get to final desired results.

Here is example data:

**table**

```
+-----------+------------+
| worker    | condition  |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
| 2         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 2         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 2         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 3         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
| 3         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
| 3         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
```

**desired results**

```
+-----------+------------+
| worker    | text field |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | A and B    |
+-----------+------------+
| 2         | A          |
+-----------+------------+
| 3         | B          |
+-----------+------------+
```

The condition in the table may evaluate to multiple cases like A, B, and C. In the example I used only A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select worker,
       (case when min(condition) = max(condition) then max(condition)
             else 'A and B'
        end) from table
where condition in ('A', 'B')
group by worker;
```

The `where` condition may not be necessary, but you seem focused only on As and Bs.

More generally, you could do:

```
select worker,
       (case when min(condition) = max(condition) then max(condition)
             else min(condition) + ' - ' + max(condition)
        end) from table
group by worker;
```

Comment: The condition in the table may evaluate to multiple cases like A, B, and C. In the example I used only A and B.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you *actually* ask.  If you have another question that involves more conditions, then you should ask that as *another* question.  Modifying this question is rude, because it can invalidate the answers already here, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: I agree that modifying question would be rude. Do not worry. The question is left unchanged, the comment just asks for more general situation that I have not thought up before. Your answer has been a good inspiration for the solution. Thank you!

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin . . . You probably want aggregate string concatenation.  That is unnecessarily complex in SQL Server, using XML and the `stuff()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to aggregate distinct `condition`s into  a string. I assume your condition doesn't contain forbidden XML characters as  & or <. (It would be just a bit slower otherwise).

```
declare @t table (
   worker int, 
   condition varchar(10)
);
insert @t values
 (1,'A')
,(1,'A')
,(1,'A')
,(1,'A')
,(2,'B')
,(2,'B')
,(2,'B')
,(3,'C')
,(3,'A')
,(3,'B');

select worker,
    conditions=stuff((select distinct ' and ' + t2.condition 
        from @t t2 
        where t2.worker = t1.worker
        order by ' and ' + t2.condition
        for xml path('')),1,5,'') 

from @t t1
group by worker ;
```

Comment: Looks promising:-)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to apply a [WHERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause to aggregate data you want to use [Having](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180199.aspx):

> Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. HAVING can
>   be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a
>   GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a
>   WHERE clause.

ie:

```
SELECT
    worker,
    ,help_column_A=sum(case when condition='A' then 1 else 0 end)
    ,help_column_B=sum(case when condition='B' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    worker
HAVING
    sum(case when condition='A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    OR sum(case when condition='B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: How can I end up with desired results through HAVING?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your desired results, if your question is "How can I efficiently check if at least one record exists in group?" then the use of GROUP BY and HAVING will allow you to do that.  If your question is how to format the result so that you concatenate a string representing the 'conditions' a worker matches?  this is a different question.